# Is there any good UML modeling tool with version control support?

Tags: uml

I've been searching the internet a lot for UML modeling tools that support version control systems, like svn, but I haven't found anything about it. Does anyone know a good uml modeling tool, preferrably free, with version control support?

Comment: In general, you get what you pay for. You're more likely to get richer version control support in a commercial product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try BOUML : http://bouml.free.fr

It has a "file control" plugin that should do the trick among cvs, svn and others

Answer (score 1):

Not free but EnterpriseArchitect [Sparx Systems](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au) is pretty cheap and works well with various version control systems.

Comment: No it's not. While it can integrate with source control it's not recommended at all. In fact it's a disaster. Having a dedicated database is the way to go with EA.

Comment: Actually Sparx Systems recomends both approaches. In a large geographically disperse modeling team, using a SVN server or the like to check out a small branch of the model to work on locally will be much faster than trying to serialise the information across an ODBC connection. See page 13 of their deployment whitepaper: http://www.sparxsystems.com/downloads/whitepapers/EA_Deployment.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a mac OmniGraffle works pretty well, but I wouldn't call it full-featured.

As for the SVN, why don't you just save the UML layout file itself in the SVN, that way you don't need the integration.

Comment: There are many ways you can benefit from VC in UML. If you just upload your layout to VC, you won't see the changes made in it. Especially when it is a binary file. That way you can use a shared folder or cloud. There is no way you can tell which changes were made in which commit, why and by whom. Also no merges. That's the whole point of using VC.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but Visual Paradigm might do the trick.